# Getting TypeError: (intermediate value).Bar is not a function with react and chart.js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to display bar chart using chart.js and react.js. But I am getting an error saying `"TypeError: (intermediate value).Bar is not a function"` and I'm unable to get any solution for it. Need a help here.
Thank You.

The react code for problem is:

```
var React = require("react");

var Chart = React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps: function() {
        barChartData = {
            labels : ["Narendra Modi", "Manmohan Singh"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
                    highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
                    highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : [65, 35]
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    onload: function() {
        var ctx     = document.getElementById("canvas_poll").getContext("2d");
        var myBar   = new Chart(ctx).Bar(this.props.barChartData, {
                        scaleGridLineWidth : 1,
                      });
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.onload();
    },

    render: function() {

        return (
            <div>
                <canvas id="canvas_poll" height="10" width="600"></canvas>
            </div>
        );
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chart.js defines a `Chart` class, which you’re trying to use, but you’re overwriting it by creating a React component named `Chart`, so when your component tries to use the Chart.js `Chart` class, it instead sees itself, the React component, and fails. Pick a different name so you’re not overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I am not getting that error. Now just getting some chart.js related error. Thanks again :)